# Solving $ \mathbf{y'}(t) = \omega(t) + \frac{1}2\omega(t) \times \mathbf{y}(t) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve:

$$ \mathbf{y'}(t) = \omega(t) + \frac{1}2\omega(t) \times \mathbf{y}(t) $$

or equally:

$$y_1′(t) = \omega_1(t) + \frac{1}2(\omega_2(t)y_3(t) - \omega_3(t)y_2(t))$$
$$y_2′(t) = \omega_2(t) + \frac{1}2(\omega_3(t)y_1(t) - \omega_1(t)y_3(t))$$
$$y_3′(t) = \omega_3(t) + \frac{1}2(\omega_1(t)y_2(t) - \omega_2(t)y_1(t))$$

I found this: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/sysode/sode0205.pdf but I couldn't figure out how to proceed.